# Doubts when calculating this space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good day for all, I am finding this quotient vector space $\mathbb{R_3[x]/R_1[x]}$, Where $\mathbb{R_3[x]}$  represents the space of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to 3 with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, in a similar way for $\mathbb{R_1[x]}$; but I have some doubts when finding the equivalence class of any polynomial $u(x)$.

My work:

I have defined $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ both in $\mathbb{R_3[x]}$  and declare that $uRv$ if and only if $u-v\in\mathbb{R_1[x]}$. Let's suppose $u(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$ and $v(x)=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3$ then $u-v\in\mathbb{R_1[x]}\rightarrow u-v=c+dx$ with $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.
I equate and solve the following system of equations
$(a_0-b_0)+(a_1-b_1)x+(a_2-b_2)x^2+(a_3-b_3)x^3=c+dx$

$a_0-b_0=c \rightarrow a_0=c+b_0$

$a_1-b_1=d\rightarrow a_1=d+b_1$

$a_2-b_2=0\rightarrow a_2=b_2$

$a_3-b_3=0\rightarrow a_3=b_3$

Then I know that I have to replace but I do not find the general form of $u + W$ (the equivalence class of a generic polynomial in the quotient space). I ask for your precious help with this and I would also like to know if my reasoning is correct. By the way what is the equivalence class of this polynomial $u(x)=x+x^2-x^3$?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Two 3rd degree polynomials are equivalent if their difference is a first degree polynomial. As you have shown in excruciating detail, this means that the 3rd degree polynomials must have the same coefficients for the cubic and quadratic terms. Obviously, the linear and constant terms can be anything, as you can add any arbitrary degree 1 polynomial without changing the class. So the class of any 3rd degree polynomial will consist of all polynomials with the same cubic and quadratic terms. For example, the class of $x + x^2 - x^3$ is $-x^3 + x^2 +\Bbb R_1[x]$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you very much for your attention, then based on my previous calculations the class of any polynomial $u(x)$ would be $u+\mathbb{R_1[x]}=\{c+a_0+(d+a_1)x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\}?$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry for my ignorance, but I'm new to this, how would the next polynomial class be $5x$,$2$,$1+3x-2x^2$? I feel that if I see these examples I could understand the case. Thanks

Comment: The class for $u = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2+ a_3x^3$ would be $$u + \Bbb R_1[x] = \{ c + dx + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 \mid c, d \in \Bbb R\}$$ Since $c, d$ are arbitrary, it is pointless to keep worrying about $a_0$ and $a_1$. Adding them to one arbitrary value just gives you another arbitrary value. As for your second question. I cannot figure out what you are trying to say. What "next" polynomial class? "Next" indicates some type of ordering that is not present here. And what do you mean by the 3 values you listed?

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences, I have already understood your idea. Let me see if I am clear with this example, correct me if I am wrong, please. Let $u(x) =1-4x+8^2+5x^3$, then $u+\mathbb{R_1[x]}=\{c+dx+8x^2+5x^3:c,d\in\mathbb{R}\}$?,Then for example the polynomials k(x)=$3x+8x^2+5x^3$ and $t(x)=4-2x+8x^2+5x^3$ belong to this class?

Comment: yes. A polynomial's class is the set of all polynomials with the same quadratic and cubic terms as it.

Comment: Then for example the polynomials $k(x)=3x+8x^2+5x^3$ and $t(x)=4−2x+8x^2+5x^3$ belong to the $u$ class? and $p(x)=3x$ not.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh, really thank you very much for all your valuable attention. A final question on the subject, according to the calculations I showed above is indifferent if I write the class of $u = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2+ a_3x^3$ in either form: $u+\mathbb{R_1[x]}=\{c+a_0+(d+a_1)x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\}$ or $u + \Bbb R_1[x] = \{ c + dx + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 \mid c, d \in \Bbb R\}$ ? In what class would this polynomial $p(x) =3x$ be?

Comment: Before I get to your question, first let me make sure you are understanding the notation. $\{c+a_0+(d+a_1)x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\}$ is an "abuse of notation". It is not a complete notation for a set, because $c$ and $d$ are undefined (the $a_i$ values and $x$ are defined in the context). The correct notation for this set would be $\{c+a_0+(d+a_1)x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\mid c, d \in \Bbb R\}$. That is, $c,d$ are dummy variables replaced by various real numbers in each set element. But since this sort of set happens a lot in Math, we drop the definition of $c, d$ as a sort of abbreviation.

Comment: Now, $\{c+a_0+(d+a_1)x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\mid c, d \in \Bbb R\} = \{c+dx+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\mid c, d \in \Bbb R\}$ because $c,d$ are arbitrary real numbers. So adding the $a_0$ to $c$ and $a_1$ to $d$ just changes the arbitrary real numbers to other arbitrary real numbers, which are also included in that same set. Therefore, while the first notation is the same set, it includes needless complications that hide what is important here. $a_0$ and $a_1$ have no significance to this set definition, so why include them in it?

Comment: Finally: when $u = 3x$, then $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 3, a_2 = 0, a_3 = 0$, so let me ask *you* what is $u + \Bbb R_1[x]$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you very much for all your help. In this case, I suppose $u + \Bbb R_1[x]=\{ c + dx \mid c, d \in \Bbb R\}$ I am right?

Comment: Exactly. Because this particular $u \in \Bbb R_1[x]$, we have that $u + \Bbb R_1[x] = \Bbb R_1[x]$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you very much really. You have been very attentive with my doubts. This topic is new to me and currently I do not have a linear algebra teacher, I am studying on my own. I will continue to do exercises, but I would like you to do me the favor of advising me. How can I contact you? Greetings from Venezuela.